# Why SQL server query very slow on passing variable in stored procedure declared in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_Test   
    (@scope varchar(10))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @test TABLE(id INT)

    INSERT INTO @test
        SELECT a.id
        FROM a
        INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.aid
        WHERE b.mastername = 'XXASQQ189'
 
    DECLARE @an int = (SELECT id FROM animal WHERE scope = @scope)

    SELECT
        value1, value2, ...., valueN
    FROM 
        tableN ab
    WHERE
        id > @an
        OR ab.id IN (SELECT id FROM @test)
END
```

This is super slow. What is the reason for it and what is the proper solutions to overcome this?

Comment: Whuy, out of interest, do you use a table variable? Why not use a subquery in the `WHERE`, probably in an `EXISTS`?

Comment: The query is slow, not passing a `varchar(10)` argument. You gain nothing by storing intermediate data into a table variable without even a primary key or any indexes. Right now you force the database to scan the entire `tableN` table and check the table variable for any matches without indexing

Comment: There could be tons of reasons. If the amount of data you are trying to insert into a table variable is large, it is better to use a TEMP table #test  instead of variable.  You can add indexes to temp table.  Check indexes.  If you can send over the execution plan and a repeatable example we can help a lot more.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Why is the table variable used at all? If the `id` and `aid` fields have proper indexes, it would be orders of magnitude faster to replace `ab in (select id from @test)` with an INNER JOIN or even an `and EXISTS (select 1
 from a
 inner join b on a.id = b.aid where a.id=ab.id)`. The query optimizer would use only the indexes covering the ID fields to quickly find matches

Answer (score 0):

I've done my best to put comments into your code to explain why some of this is inefficient at a high level.  There is a few other reasons I've left out that is more advance knowledge, but what I put below is just for starters.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_Test   
    (@scope varchar(10))
AS
BEGIN
    /*Normally a variable temp table in SQL will not join well with other tables and is normally recommended to use a #Temp Table. Although, with how I've read your code, you probably don't even need this table and could return everything in one simple statement which I will write below. */
    DECLARE @test TABLE(id INT)
```

/* nothing wrong with this section */
INSERT INTO @test
SELECT a.id
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.aid
/* this is tricky, without the knowledge of how much data is in the table, you may be returning a random ID back to @an.  To make sure only one record is returned, you should do a TOP 1, this would also speed up the select */
DECLARE @an int = (SELECT id FROM animal WHERE scope = @scope)

```
    SELECT
        value1, value2, ...., valueN
    FROM 
        tableN ab
    WHERE
        id > @an
```

/*the biggest problem is the IN selection here.  A IN statement forces the code to SCAN the entire table.  The reason is it doesn't know how many records it needs to check/compare to.  This will always make things slower. */
AND ab IN (SELECT id FROM @test)
END

Below is how I would have taken a shot at writing the code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_TEST ( @Scope VARCHAR(10))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        value1, value2, ...., valueN
    FROM
        tableN TN
    WHERE 
        EXISTS 
            (SELECT --This is known as a partial join trick
                1
            FROM 
                a
            INNER JOIN 
                b 
                ON a.id = b.aid
            WHERE
                a.id = TN.id)
        --Note this could still be broken out if there was a performance concern but on a table
        --less then 100k rows, this should be fine.
        AND tn.id > (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM animal WHERE scope = @scope);
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the table variable. You can put ALL of that into a single statement, and SQL Server can do a much better job that way.

Here's the basic version:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_Test   
    (@scope varchar(10))
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT
        value1, value2, ...., valueN
    FROM 
        tableN ab
    WHERE
        id > (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM animal WHERE scope = @scope)
        AND ab IN (
           SELECT a.id
           FROM a
           INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.aid
        )
END
```

Or if we switch to `EXISTS`, which tends to perform even better:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_Test   
    (@scope varchar(10))
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT   ab.value1, ab.value2, ...., ab.valueN
    FROM  tableN ab
    WHERE
       EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
           FROM a
           INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.aid
           WHERE a.id = ab.ab
       ) AND ab.id > (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM animal WHERE scope = @scope)

END
```